# Module not found : can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`I found a solution on internet that helped a lot of users. But in this case it din't helped me.`

`here is my package.json`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "git-revision-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^3.0.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.3",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.67",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "clone": "^2.1.2",
    "config": "^3.2.3",
    "curl": "^0.1.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "dmn-js": "10.1.0",
    "dmn-js-properties-panel": "^0.6.2",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jodit-react": "^1.0.70",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.2",
    "node-libcurl": "^2.3.3",
    "promise": "^8.0.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.9.0",
    "re-resizable": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-cron-generator": "^1.1.5",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-csv-downloader": "^2.2.0",
    "react-d3-tree": "^1.17.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-drop-zone": "^3.0.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.9.0",
    "react-intl": "^4.5.0",
    "react-json-pretty": "^2.1.0",
    "react-json-view": "^1.19.1",
    "react-mdl": "^1.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^3.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.3",
    "react-tree-graph": "^4.0.0",
    "react-xml-parser": "^1.1.8",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-dynamic-modules": "^3.5.0",
    "redux-dynamic-modules-thunk": "^3.5.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

`Here is my webpack`

```
const config = merge.smart(common.config, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  output: {
    filename: "js/[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "js/[name].chunk.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "./dist"),
    writeToDisk: true,
    compress: true,
    inline: true,
    port: 3001,
    publicPath: common.basePath,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: true,
    openPage: common.basePath.replace(/^\//, ""),
    hot: true,
    progress: true,
    overlay: true,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: ``,
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
        secure: false,
        headers: {
          Host: ''
        }
      }
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'inferno': ''
    }
  },
});

module.exports = config;
```

`i have tried this solution also but not usefull`

```
config.node = {
  fs: 'empty',
}

"browser": {
  "fs": false,
  "path": false,
  "os": false
}
```

[Im getting this error, even after installing all the dependencies that npm mjml-react requires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAgHf.png)

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\malliar\Dap\Dap-ui\dap-management-ui\acceleratorUI\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader'
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\malliar\Dap\Dap-ui\dap-management-ui\acceleratorUI\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader'
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\malliar\Dap\Dap-ui\dap-management-ui\acceleratorUI\node_modules\uglify-js\tools'
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mjml' in 'C:\Users\malliar\Dap\Dap-ui\dap-management-ui\acceleratorUI\node_modules\mjml-react\dist\es\src'

Answer (score 3):

It is not available in your browser.
You can use it only when you are running your app with node.
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: No it is happening, only when i try to import mjml components,
if i remove
import 'mjml' from 'mjml-react'; 
then the application will run properly without any errors

Comment: can mjml-react only be installable on node.js application. Can't we install  it on NGINX web application. If we can then please guide me how to render.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I found a solution for this problem. npm MJML-REACT might not work here. So, I started looking for some other libraries which works fine with my NGINX web application.

As a result, I found a library which is mjml-browser(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mjml-browser)with which, I could finally integrate mjml into my application.

What you have to do is ,
Download npm mjml-browser..https://www.npmjs.com/package/mjml-browser
Import it into your application (import mjml2html from "mjml-browser")

```
mjmltohtml = () => {
        let vtl = "mjmlCode";
        let html;
        try {
            html = mjml2html(vtl).html;
            //console.log(html)
        } catch (error) {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({ mjmlhtml: html })
    }
```

This code will Convert your mjml into html.

Thank me later